# Access mat accordion value in another component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to get the value from my mat accordion component but am not sure how to access it. The values I want to access is the `panelOpenState` parameter which is tied to the opened and closed values

*Mat accordion HTML*

```
<mat-accordion>
    <mat-expansion-panel (opened)="data.panelOpenState === true" (closed)="data.panelOpenState === false" [expanded]="data.expanded">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header (click)="stateValue()">
            <mat-panel-title>
                {{ data?.title }}
            </mat-panel-title>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

*Mat accordion TS*

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SidePanelAccordianData } from './side-panel-accordian.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-side-panel-accordian',
  templateUrl: './side-panel-accordian.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./side-panel-accordian.component.scss']
})
export class SidePanelAccordianComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() data: SidePanelAccordianData;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  stateValue() {
    this.data.panelOpenState = !this.data.panelOpenState;
  }

}
```

*Mat accordion model*

```
export class SidePanelAccordianData {
  public title: string = '';
  public panelOpenState: boolean;
  public expanded: boolean;


  constructor(args) {
    this.title = args.title;
    this.panelOpenState = args.panelOpenState;
    this.expanded = args.expanded;
  }
}
```

Now I am trying to get the value of the `panelOpenState` parameter in the below component

*HTML*

```
<app-side-panel-accordian [data]="{title:'Title', panelOpenState: panelOpenState, expanded: secondDriverExpanded}">
    <div class="inner-row-data">
      <form-input [formStatus]="formStatus" [parentFormGroup]="setupForm" [data]="{
        formControlName: 'secondDriverName',
        name: 'secondDriverName',
      }" (onBlur)="setSecondDriverDetails('name')">
      </form-input>
    </div>
</app-side-panel-accordian>
```

*TS*

I need help here - how can I get the value of `panelOpenState` from the mat accordion common component? I basically just want to know whether the accordion is open or closed.

Please assist me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways to do this that come to mind. You could use  the angular [viewchild decorator](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild), which would greatly depend on how the rest of your html is organized. The easiest approach would be to use a service to communicate the state to any component that cares about it. That service might look like this:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AccordianStateService {
  private _openStateBehaviorSubject = new BehaviorSubject(false); // or set the state to null, or use a subject and don't set it at all.
  public openState$ = _openStateBehaviorSubject.asObservable();

  public setOpenState(value: boolean) {
    this._openStateBehaviorSubject.next(value);
  }
}
```

Then, in each component, you could simply inject this service via the constructor.  In the MatAccordion component, you would also make this call to the service:

```js
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SidePanelAccordianData } from './side-panel-accordian.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-side-panel-accordian',
  templateUrl: './side-panel-accordian.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./side-panel-accordian.component.scss']
})
export class SidePanelAccordianComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() data: SidePanelAccordianData;

  constructor(private accordianStateService: AccordianStateService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  stateValue() {
    this.data.panelOpenState = !this.data.panelOpenState;
    this.accordianStateService.setOpenState(this.data.panelOpenState);
  }

}
```

Lastly, in the component that wants to know the value. You would subscribe to the observable in the service like so:

```js
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private accordionStateService: AccordianStateService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.accordianStateService.openState$.subscribe({
      // do what you need to do with the value here
      // do not forget that you need to unsubscribe when this component is destroyed
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. The only query I would have is how would I differentiate the true/false value if there are more than one accordion being used in the component?

I created a new question for this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76504332/differentiate-between-mat-accordions

Comment: in that case, I would probably use an object for state management where each property is representative of a particular accordions state